# Exporting gdal geotiff to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, gdal

I am able to read in a `geotiff` file. I can plot it without problems and so on...
But I want to be able to export it to a MySQL-Server via python code and then read it in from that server again via python code.
Is this even possible and what is the best way doing it ?

Comment: you can store the file name ref ..or store a blob

Comment: okay, yes blob would work but is there a better way ?

Comment: I prefer  ..  the ref / to the file name .. (not the blob) but is a my peronal opinion

Answer (score 0):

So just my answer in case somebody needs it:
I found to methods I was happy with:

1. Blob Data

- This means the data is getting converted into binary data and then put in an mysql-table
- Then it can be extracted from that table and read in with python gdal
  The code looks like this:

  ```
    def convert_to_binary_data(self, filename):
        # Convert digital data to binary format
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            blobData = file.read()
        return blobData

    def insert_image(self, photo_path, name, table_name, id):
        binary_photo = self.convert_to_binary_data(photo_path)
        insert_blob_query = "INSERT INTO {} (id, name, photo) VALUES ('{}','{}',COMPRESS({}))".format(table_name, id,
                                                                                                      name,
                                                                                                      str(
                                                                                                          base64.b64encode(
                                                                                                              binary_photo))[
                                                                                                      1:])
        self.connection.execute(insert_blob_query)

    def read_blob_data_by_id(self, id, table_name, path):
        sql_fetch_blob_query_data = "SELECT (UNCOMPRESS(photo)) from {} where id = '{}'".format(table_name, id)
        sql_fetch_blob_query_name = "SELECT (name) from {} where id = '{}'".format(table_name, id)
        result = self.connection.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query_data)
        name = self.connection.execute(sql_fetch_blob_query_name)
        for n in name:
            nam = n[0]
        for row in result:
            photo
  ```

  = base64.b64decode(row[0])
  file_like = io.BytesIO(photo)
  img = Image.open(file_like)
  img.save(path + '\' + nam + '.jpg')

2. Reading it into array

- the second method works with a numpy array
- the numpy array is getting read in and then saved to a table
- then it can be extracted and converted back to a tif file
- this then needs additional information lioke pixelx, pixelsy ...

The code looks like this:

```
def array_to_raster(self, geotransform, array, newRasterfn, desc=None,
                    default_no_data=-99999, dtype=gdal.GDT_Float32):
    # converting array to raster and then exporting it into a file
    # reading in single value of geo settings
    if desc is None:
        desc = {'AREA_OR_POINT': 'Area', 'DataType': 'Generic'}
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
    # getting shape
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]
    # getting origin
    originX = geotransform[0]
    originY = geotransform[3]
    # getting driver for file
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    # creating file
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, dtype)
    # setting geo settings in file
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    # setting band data
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    # setting no data normal -99999
    outband.SetNoDataValue(default_no_data)
    # writing the array in data
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    # export settings
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(25832)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    # setting metadata
    outRaster.SetMetadata(desc)
    # clearing flush
    outband.FlushCache()
    # retuning value
    return outRaster
```